# npm authentication fails in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: angular, npm, azure-pipelines, npm-install, azure-pipelines-build-task

I followed the official tutorial on deploying Angular app to ADO pipelines and here is my yaml.

```
# Node.js with Angular

# Build a Node.js project that uses Angular.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '18.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- task: npmAuthenticate@0
  inputs:
    workingFile: '.npmrc'
- script: |
    npm install -g @angular/cli
    npm install
    ng build --prod
  displayName: 'npm install and build'
```

But the pipeline fails at npm install with the following error:

```
npm ERR! code E401 
npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, your authentication token seems to be invalid.
```

The app is running locally but it fails in the pipeline. For context, the app uses libs from external organization's feeds and locally I put my credentials in .npmrc in the user directory and .npmrc with registries in the project directory.

I have tried placing .npmrc with the registries used in the repo's root directory, I have also tried using my user .npmrc and saved it in a variable and later echo'ed it to a .npmrc in the yaml file but none of the above helped me to resolve the issue.

Comment: You can try to add the external organization's feeds as the Upstream Sources of the feeds in your current organization (or project) where the pipeline is in. The pipeline job access token cannot directly access the external organization feed. You can try to either set the external feed as an Upstream Source of the feed within current organization or use a service connection to the external feed.

Answer (score 1):

If the packages are in the Azure Artifacts feed from a different Azure DevOps organization than your current organization where you pipeline is in, you can set the outside feed as an upstream source of the feed within the current organization.

Then normally, if the pipeline has the access to the feed within the current organization, it also can access the packages from its upstream source feed.

More details, see "[**Configure upstream sources**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/how-to/set-up-upstream-sources?view=azure-devops)".

---

If you do not set upstream source, you need to set up a service connection for use on the **npmAuthenticate@0** task to connect to the outside feed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to authenticate before you run `npm install`.

Make sure to add this step in your pipeline before that.

Azure Artifacts Credential Provider:

This provider is a better alternative to manually handling `.npmrc` files.

```
- script: |

npm install -g vsts-npm-auth
vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc
displayName: 'Authenticate npm'
```

Other small things to double check that I have run into in the past:

Make sure the `.npmrc` file in the root references the feed URLs correctly with correct syntax.